# Scrollcontroller in flutter error Exception has occurred

Tags: dart, flutter

I have two screen , first one fetch all post from wordpress
last one fetch all videos and i use ScollController with ListView to scroll data

look to my code :

```
ScrollController _scrollController;

@override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController = new ScrollController();
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      print(_scrollController.position.pixels);
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent - 10) {
        // if we are the bottom of the page
        fetchPosts();
        //millisecs += 1500;
        //super.initState();
      }
      super.initState();
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { ....
```

when i tab between screen one to two or screen two to one

i get this error:

```
    Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (A ScrollController was used after being disposed.
Once you have called dispose() on a ScrollController, it can no longer be used.)
```

trace code:
[image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUgcV.png)

> Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
>       Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
>       D/EGL_emulation( 8157): eglMakeCurrent: 0xeeebd340: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xeee9b1d0)
>       E/eglCodecCommon( 8157): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
>       E/eglCodecCommon( 8157): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
>       I/Choreographer( 8157): Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>       D/EGL_emulation( 8157): eglMakeCurrent: 0xeef21ce0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe6f286b0)
>       D/        ( 8157): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe7123880, tid 8184
>       D/EGL_emulation( 8157): eglMakeCurrent: 0xeeebd340: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe7103370)
>       I/flutter ( 8157): _morePages: false
>       I/flutter ( 8157): statusCode: 200
>       I/flutter ( 8157): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FOUNDATION LIBRARY ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>       I/flutter ( 8157): The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for ScrollController:
>       I/flutter ( 8157): 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 1003 pos 12:
>       I/flutter ( 8157): '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not true.
>       I/flutter ( 8157):
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
>       I/flutter ( 8157): more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
>       I/flutter ( 8157): In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
>       I/flutter ( 8157):   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
>       I/flutter ( 8157):
>       I/flutter ( 8157): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
>       I/flutter ( 8157): #2      State.initState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1003:12)
>       I/flutter ( 8157): #3      _PostsPage.initState. (package:flutter_wp2019/ui/PostsLatest.dart:42:13)
>       I/flutter ( 8157): #4      ChangeNotifier.notifyListeners (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:208:21)
>       I/flutter ( 8157): #5      ChangeNotifier.notifyListeners (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:208:21)
>       I/flutter ( 8157): #6      ScrollPosition.notifyListeners (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_position.dart:692:11)
>       I/flutter ( 8157): #7      ScrollPosition.setPixels (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_position.dart:218:9)
>       I/flutter ( 8157): #8      ScrollPositionWithSingleContext.setPixels
>   (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_position_with_single_context.dart:84:18)
>       I/flutter ( 8157): #9      ScrollPositionWithSingleContext.applyUserOffset
>   (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_position_with_single_context.dart:127:5)
>       I/flutter ( 8157): #10     ScrollDragController.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_activity.dart:373:14)
>       I/flutter ( 8157): #11     ScrollableState._handleDragUpdate (package:flutter/src/widgets/scrollable.dart:470:12)
>       I/flutter ( 8157): #12     DragGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture.
>   (package:flutter/src/gestures/monodrag.dart:176:48)
>       I/flutter ( 8157): #13     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:102:24)
>       I/flutter ( 8157): #14     DragGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/monodrag.dart:176:9)
>       I/flutter ( 8157): #15     GestureArenaManager._resolveInFavorOf (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:263:12)
>       I/flutter ( 8157): #16     GestureArenaManager._resolve (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:222:9)
>       I/flutter ( 8157): #17     GestureArenaEntry.resolve (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:52:12)
>       I/flutter ( 8157): #18     OneSequenceGestureRecognizer.resolve (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:166:13)
>       I/flutter ( 8157): #19     DragGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/monodrag.dart:154:11)
>       I/flutter ( 8157): #20     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:73:12)
>       I/flutter ( 8157): #21     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:101:11)
>       I/flutter ( 8157): #22     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:180:19)
>       I/flutter ( 8157): #23     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:158:22)
>       I/flutter ( 8157): #24     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:138:7)
>       I/flutter ( 8157): #25     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue
>   (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:101:7)
>       I/flutter ( 8157): #26     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket
>   (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:85:7)
>       I/flutter ( 8157): #27     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:168:13)
>       I/flutter ( 8157): #28     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:122:5)
>       I/flutter ( 8157): (elided 2 frames from class _AssertionError)
>       I/flutter ( 8157):
>       I/flutter ( 8157): The ScrollController sending notification was:
>       I/flutter ( 8157):   ScrollController#bcc47(one client, offset 21.4)
>       I/flutter ( 8157): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/chatty  ( 8157): uid=10083(com.example.flutterwp2019) 1.ui identical 16 lines
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/zygote  ( 8157): Do partial code cache collection, code=29KB, data=23KB
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/chatty  ( 8157): uid=10083(com.example.flutterwp2019) 1.ui identical 1 line
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/zygote  ( 8157): After code cache collection, code=29KB, data=23KB
>       I/zygote  ( 8157): Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/chatty  ( 8157): uid=10083(com.example.flutterwp2019) 1.ui identical 11 lines
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/zygote  ( 8157): Do partial code cache collection, code=59KB, data=40KB
>       I/zygote  ( 8157): After code cache collection, code=59KB, data=40KB
>       I/zygote  ( 8157): Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
>       I/flutter ( 8157): 30.00837053571422
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/flutter ( 8157): 42.86551339285711
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/flutter ( 8157): 55.72265625
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/flutter ( 8157): 71.41741071428567
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/flutter ( 8157): 88.56863839285711
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/flutter ( 8157): 105.71986607142856
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/flutter ( 8157): 120.24285714285713
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/flutter ( 8157): 117.38013392857141
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/flutter ( 8157): 110.24843749999997
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/flutter ( 8157): 93.09720982142858
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/flutter ( 8157): 63.0888392857143
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/flutter ( 8157): 23.11116071428569
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/flutter ( 8157): 0.0
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/flutter ( 8157): 1.4313616071428896
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/flutter ( 8157): 8.58816964285711
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/flutter ( 8157): 24.006696428571445
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/flutter ( 8157): 41.15792410714289
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/flutter ( 8157): 64.00948660714289
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/flutter ( 8157): 85.4296875
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/flutter ( 8157): 108.28125
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/flutter ( 8157): 120.24285714285713
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/flutter ( 8157): 2.8376116071428896
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/flutter ( 8157): 7.131696428571445
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/flutter ( 8157): 11.42578125
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/flutter ( 8157): 18.557477678571445
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/flutter ( 8157): 24.28292410714289
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/flutter ( 8157): 39.977678571428555
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/flutter ( 8157): 57.12890625
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/flutter ( 8157): 77.14285714285717
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/flutter ( 8157): 97.13169642857144
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/flutter ( 8157): 115.71428571428572
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/flutter ( 8157): 120.24285714285713
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/flutter ( 8157): _morePages: false
>       I/flutter ( 8157): statusCode: 200
>       I/flutter ( 8157): _morePages: false
>       I/flutter ( 8157): statusCode: 400
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/chatty  ( 8157): uid=10083(com.example.flutterwp2019) 1.ui identical 22 lines
>       I/flutter ( 8157): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not
>   true.
>       I/flutter ( 8157): _morePages: false
>       I/flutter ( 8157): statusCode: 200

[image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUgcV.png)

Thanks Advance

Comment: What line points the stack trace to as cause for the exception?

Comment: How make a trace code by flutter run -v or what?

Comment: There shouldn't be anything to do. Just post the full error output.

Answer (score 8):

`super.initState()` is on the wrong location

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState(); // <<< added

    _scrollController = new ScrollController();
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      print(_scrollController.position.pixels);
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent - 10) {
        // if we are the bottom of the page
        fetchPosts();
        //millisecs += 1500;
        //super.initState();
      }
      // super.initState(); // <<< removed
    });

  }
```

Comment: Can you please update your answer with the code you have now. The old code is definitely wrong because `super.initState()` there is only called when `_scrollController` calls the listener.

Comment: what about dispose    `@override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }`

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: when i remove override dispose application word fine but i get another error message:Could not load source 'dart:convert/runtime/libconvert_patch.dart': <source not available>.

Comment: How can it work fine with this error message`. Try https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#flutter-installation-corrupted

Comment: Thanks Günter Zöchbauer, now  it work fine ,But I want to ask if you should override dispose method to dispose state and ScrollController or not ?

Comment: Yes, normally you should dispose all instances you create in your code that have a `dispose()` method and this should be done in  `@overrid void dispose() { ..., super.dispose();}`

Comment: If this answer fixes your issue please mark it as correct so that future users who face the same issue can easily find it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this into the widget where you are initializing the scroll controller:

```
@override
void dispose() {
   _controller.dispose();
   super.dispose();
}
```

and move the super.init() above the intialization